# Nodejs: CORS for POST works, GET does NOT

Tags: node.js, get, cors

I'm trying to fetch the contents of a file "xxx.html" from my nodejs/express server.
But whenever I try to get the file with Javascript fetch:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.text();
```

I get the CORS error:

"Access to fetch at 'https://rez-dev.workbest.de/rezept_camera_grid.html' from origin 'https://docproeller.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I've been reading about cors for hours and hours now, but cannot find the cause of this problem.
Now I found a 'cors-tester' online.

Results:

- cors request with method GET does NOT WORK
  https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Frez-dev.workbest.de%2F&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcors-test.codehappy.dev%2F&method=get
- cors request with method POST WORKS
  https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Frez-dev.workbest.de%2F&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcors-test.codehappy.dev%2F&method=post

Every help or hint is very welcome.

Server:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

// Use static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Use json- and url-encoding
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

// Use CORS
// Allow all Origins
app.use(cors());

https_port=443;
sslServer = https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(ssl_server_key)),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(ssl_server_cert))
      }, app);
      sslServer.listen(https_port, () => console.log("Secure Server is listening on port " + sslServer.address().port));
```

Comment: Did you try to move `app.use(cors());` higher right after `const cors = require("cors");`?

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Anatoly and some other sources put me into the right direction. The solution is actually to move the command line higher up:

```
  // Init app
  const app = express();
  // Use CORS
  // Allow all Origins
  app.use(cors());
```